# One Time Login URL not Received : Looking for a Spare Solution

Tags: users, emails

Some (only a few) of my users do not receive the "one time login url" mail when they want to reset their (forgotten) password (also checked in spam and trash).

The odd thing is that if I personnaly send them a mail from postmaster@... (using thunderbird for instance), they receive it. I find no explanation to that.

So, I envisage to personnaly send them their [user:one-time-login-url]. Can I do that ? How ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the user module function `user_pass_reset_url($account)` is used to generate one time login url. if you know the uid of the user you can load that user object and pass it as the `$account` for that function and send the generated link in your custom email.

Comment: I am not a smart programmer ; I can find the user Id (no pb with that) ; but then, how can I call this function, ... and get the answer (to capy-paste it) ?

Comment: As an alternative, I have seen that one-time-login.module generates a csv file which contains the URL : is this csv stored somewhere (where it can be consulted) ? As an other alternative, would it be possible that the administrator be in copy of the mail sent to the user ?

Comment: Im not sure about the one-time-login.module as I have not used that module personally. But if you have your own custom module, you can use the code in my answer. Just call the function `user_pass_reset_url($account)` and pass the `user` object as `$account` you should have your url  and if you also have a look at [hook_mail](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_mail/7.x). Im sure you can cc the users with administrator roles while sending mail.

Comment: Thank you Sanjok : I tried to develop a small php which calls user_pass_reset_url($account) function, as you suggest, but got some errors that I am not skilly enough to overpass (e.g. : Fatal error: Class 'DrupalDefaultEntityController' not found in /home/bapaparoisse/www/www/modules/user/user.module on line 300). I was suggested to use drush uli USERNAME which seems to work (I tested it successfully). Thanks again for your answer.